# Problem with the [cling] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [cling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cling) tag is currently related to [the LLVM-based C++ interpreter shipped by CERN](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling).
However the tag is often (ab)used by people seeking help with [a Java/Android library](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) and many questions are not correctly tagged.

I do not know what can be done for this, but I thought to bring some attention.

Answer (score 13):

I created tag [android-cling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cling) and retagged all Android specific Cling questions with [android-cling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cling).

I added a tag summary too, specifying which questions should use it, along with a brief tag wiki for the new tag.

These questions were incorrectly tagged with [cling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cling) which is for CERN's C++ interpreter.

Comment: Is this sufficient though ? I am afraid that you may have to retag regularly as people using the library are wont to use the shortest tag available (`cling`).

Comment: @MatthieuM. When user types cling, android-cling comes in the suggestions, so hoping they will choose it. I added a tag summary too, specifying which questions should use it, along with a brief tag wiki for the new tag. Should I do anything else?

Comment: I doubt there is anything more *you* can do, I just wonder whether it will be sufficient given that many users seem to try to beat the record of fastest question composition and many others seems not to understand how to use tags at all.

Comment: That is true @MatthieuM. Unfortunately, users don't tag properly :(